# Quickbooks API - How to create a charge using stored bank account

Tags: java, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

I am using QuickBooks Online. Using payments api I have stored customer's bank account info to Quickbooks. Now I want to create a charge against the stored bank account using payments api. I couldn't find a way to do that. I know how to create a charge using stored credit card but I couldn't find a way to provide bank account info instead while making `/quickbooks/v4/payments/charges` api call.

Can a charge be created against stored bank account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the docs on `eChecks` / `debits`:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/payments/echecks

Specifically, this section:

> Create a debit
>
> REQUEST URL
>
> Sandbox Base URL: https://sandbox.api.intuit.com
>
> Production Base URL: https://api.intuit.com
>
> Operation:
>
> POST /quickbooks/v4/payments/echecks
>
> Content type: application/json
>
> To process an E-check, you create a new debit object.

Where it shows an example like this:

```
{  
  "amount":"1.11",
  "bankAccount":{  
      "name":"Fname LName",
      "routingNumber":"490000018",
      "accountNumber":"11000000333456781",
      "accountType":"PERSONAL_CHECKING",
      "phone":"1234567890"
  },
  "context":{  
      "deviceInfo":{  
        "id":"1",
        "type":"type",
        "longitude":"longitude",
        "latitude":"",
        "phoneNumber":"phonenu",
        "macAddress":"macaddress",
        "ipAddress":"34"
      }
  },
  "paymentMode":"WEB",
  "checkNumber":"12345678",
  "description":"Check Auth test call"
}
```

Together with a note that says:

```
bankAccountOnFile:
required if neither bankAccount nor token are specified
string 
The bank account details that have been previously stored on file.
```

TLDR: Use the `create a debit` endpoint and specify the `bankAccountOnFile` `id` value in the request.

Comment: Thanks a lot Keith. I will try it and get back.

Comment: Working as expected. Thank you